# Are abstract nouns formed from adjectives the same as being the adjective?

Tags: terminology

For example, in English we can use "-ness" to make abstract nouns from adjectives, and it would mean "the state of being(the adjective)", "the quality of being(the adjective)", or "the measure of being(the adjective)." However, those definitions seem unclear. Are they saying something like "tallness" is the same as "being tall"? We can say things like "the act of smoking" where the act is smoking, and we can also say "his best quality is being kind" where "quality" is the same as "being kind." Thus, it would be plausible to state that "the quality of being(the adjective)" is the same as "being(the adjective)" in the same way "the act of smoking" is the same as "smoking." However, this way of thinking doesn't seem to work in real life.

> I turned down the brightness. (correct)
>
> I turned down the being bright. (sounds wrong)
>
> I have kindness. (correct)
>
> I have being kind. (sounds wrong)

This applies to other abstract nouns that are related to adjectives such as bravery and honesty. If abstract nouns such as "-ness" do not mean "being(the adjective)" then what do they mean?

Comment: There are a number of different kinds of abstraction. The devisers of the artificial language Lojban identified "event", "quantity", "quality", "statement" and "truth-value" as some common kinds. (I don't know whether they were drawing on any published work for this analysis).

Comment: Well, what is the difference between, say, "the quality of being bright" and "being bright"?

Comment: Your examples make this look more like a syntax problem than a semantics problem. ‘Being bright’ and ‘the quality of being bright’ fit different slots; in very crude terms, one is an action and the other is an object.